# How to convert values into color information for circle in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to convert values into color information in Colormap. I have z values and would like to map z value into circle shape. For example, I have a coordinate (xi,yi) and would like to draw a circle centering this coordinate with z value mapped into colormap. However, it is not drawing any circle. Below is my code.

```
r = 100
color_map = cm.Oranges
norm = Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=100)
rgba = color_map(norm(zi))

CS = plt.Circle((xi, yi), r, color=rgba[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of issues actually. You didn't create any axes and you are using color map incorrectly. So, create your circles and note how color_map is used. Then add it to a created axes object.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 100
color_map = plt.get_cmap("Oranges")
circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.2, color=color_map(0.66))
circle2 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color=color_map(0.45))
circle3 = plt.Circle((1, 1), 0.2, color=color_map(0.2), clip_on=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(circle1)
ax.add_artist(circle2)
ax.add_artist(circle3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This explains why. One more question, I am plotting on top of image which has size if 1000x800. And I loaded it with figure function (fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi)). In this case, how should I add plots to my igure?

Comment: Just use this keyword when calling plt.subplots, i.e.: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20), dpi=300)

Comment: I've used this code and it seems by calling subplot, it initialized image. This is my code 'fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi) plt.imshow(imgdata) circle1 = plt.Circle((xi[0], yi[0]), r, color=color_map(zi[0])) fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20), dpi=300) 'ax.add_artist(circle1)'

Comment: I just fixed code and it worked. Thank you! This is the final version. _circle1 = plt.Circle((xi[0], yi[0]), r, color=color_map(zi[0]))

    fig.add_subplot(111).add_artist(circle1)_